# Connecting to GeoServer OGC API Tiles through QGIS

Tags: qgis, geoserver, ogc-api

I wanted to connect with QGIS to OGC API TILES Layer "tiger:tiger_roads" (Manhattan (NY) roads) which is accessible through GeoServer version 2.24 snapshot by default.

The access point is this one: http://localhost:8083/geoserver/ogc/tiles/v1/collections/tiger:tiger_roads/tiles/EPSG:4326?f=text%2Fhtml

I can see this layer in the GeoServer Preview through WMTS but I would like to see the same data from QGIS. I tried to add the vector tiles layer through Add Layer -> Add Vector Layer. As the source I would need to choose OGC API.

What is OGC API endpoint to this layer?

I tried several variants but still have error `Invalid Data Source: OGCAPI:....is not a valid or recognized data source.`

Variants I tried:

`http://localhost:8083/geoserver/ogc/tiles/v1/collections/tiger:tiger_roads`
`http://localhost:8083/geoserver/ogc/tiles/v1/collections/tiger:tiger_roads?f=application%2Fjson`

[image]

I also tried to connect to gnosis vector tiles in the same way through OGC API option supported by QGIS with this endpoint and I succeeded:
https://maps.gnosis.earth/ogcapi/collections/Daraa:AeronauticCrv

Comment: can QGIS see `http://localhost:8083`

Comment: It should. Proxy is disabled in QGIS. How can I check it please?